# Flutter Web - Error: Unsupported operation: _Namespace when uploading an image to FirebaseStorage

Tags: flutter, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I'm unable to upload the image to Firebase Storage, because I get the error

`Error: Unsupported operation: \_Namespace`

This is the problematic code:

`Uint8List imageData = await image.readAsBytes();`

[image: Error: Unsupported operation: _Namespace]

The whole method:

```
  Future uploadFile(File fileToUpload) async {
    File image = fileToUpload;
    final fileName = image.path.split('/').last;
    final destination = 'files/$fileName';

    try {
      final ref = _firebaseStorage.ref(destination).child('file/');

      if (kIsWeb) {
        Uint8List imageData = await image.readAsBytes();

        await ref.putData(imageData);
      } else {
        await ref.putFile(image);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      //TODO add a logger
      print('error occured: ${e.toString()}');
  }
```

If useful, in the index.html i have the following

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.4.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.4.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.4.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

How do you suggest to upload the image to Firebase Storage?